# What are Spanish common tense and literary tense

Tags: tiempos-verbales

I hear there are common tenses and literary tense in Spanish, although I have tried to google it, I'm still struggling it and very curious.

To smoothly self-study Spanish, and avoiding unnecessary frustration, I have to know it.

Can you list common tenses native speakers use every day that I must learn?

Will literary tenses be automatically learned if they rarely use them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a table of all the conjugation forms in Spanish: [LINK](http://www.edu.xunta.es/centros/iesastelleiras/?q=system/files/CONJUGACI%C3%93N+DE+VERBOS+REGULARES.pdf)

### *Indicativo*

The most common forms are:

- Presente: *yo canto* → I sing
- Pretérito perfecto simple: *yo canté* → I sang
- Pretérito perfecto compuesto: *yo he cantado* → I have sung
- Pretérito imperfecto: *yo cantaba* → I sang, I used to sing, I would sing [habit in the past]
- Pretérito pluscuamperfecto: *yo había cantado* → I had sung
- Futuro: *yo cantaré* → I will sing
- Condicional: *yo cantaría* → I would sing
- Condicional perfecto: *yo habría cantado* → I would have sung

Some forms that aren't as common are:

- Futuro perfecto: *yo habré cantado* → I will have sung

These are the literary forms, so they are hardly ever used:

- **Pretérito anterior**: yo hube cantado (no direct translation to English)

### *Subjuntivo*

The most common ones are:

- Presente: *yo cante* → I sing
- Pretérito perfecto compuesto: *yo haya cantado* → I have sung
- Pretérito imperfecto: *yo cantara/cantase<sup>1</sup>* → I sang
- Pretérito pluscuamperfecto: *yo hubiera/hubiese<sup>1</sup> cantado* → I had sung

These are the literary forms, so they are hardly ever used:

- **Futuro**: *yo cantare* (no direct translation to English)
- **Futuro perfecto**: *yo hubiere cantado* (no direct translation to English)

### *Imperativo*

- Presente: *canta (tú), cantad (vosotros), cante (usted), canten (ustedes), cantemos (cantemos)* → Sing; Let's sing

The forms marked as literary are: *pretérito anterior de indicativo, futuro de subjuntivo* and *futuro perfecto de subjuntivo*. Here's how they would be used in a literary context (a book, a poem, etc.) and its equivalent in standard Spanish:

> En cuanto *hube terminado* de comer, me levanté de la mesa y me fui.= En cuanto *terminé* de comer, me levanté de la mesa y me fui.

The *pretérito anterior* is used to describe an action that happened immediately before another. It usually follows adverbs of immediateness such as *apenas, en cuanto, tan pronto como, una vez que*, etc. It's rare in modern Spanish, and usually replaced by a *pretérito perfecto simple.*

> Cuando *tuviéremos* dinero, nos iremos de vacaciones. = Cuando *tengamos* dinero, nos iremos de vacaciones.

The *futuro de subjuntivo* is used to describe a hypothetical, not finished action in the future. This form is almost nonexistant, and almost always replaced by a *presente de subjuntivo* or a *presente de indicativo* in type I if-clauses, which never take a subjunctive. It is only used in some legal texts or sayings such as "a donde fueres, haz lo que vieres".

> Para cuando los dueños *hubieren llegado* a la casa, deberás haberte ido. = Para cuando los dueños *hayan llegado* a la casa, deberás haberte ido.

The *futuro perfecto de subjuntivo* is used to describe a hypothetical, finished action in the future. This form is also almost nonexistant, and almost always replaced by a *pretérito perfecto de subjuntivo*.

None of these three forms are used in everyday Spanish, nor in formal Spanish. They are archaic forms (except for the *pretérito anterior*, but this form is also gradually disappearing), so I don't recommend learning them, or not at first at least.

---

<sup>1: *Hubiera* and *hubiese*, as well as *cantara* and *cantase* are forms that coexist and mean exactly the same thing. The *-ara, -era* form is more popular than the *-ase, -ese* one in most Spanish speaking countries. In some dialects, however, they are equally prevalent.</sup>

Comment: Why do you use *I was singing = Yo cantaba*? That's actually *past continuous* and it can offer both imperfect and perfect preterite forms: *Yo **estaba/estuve** cantando*. Also, the imperfect *cantaba* can also be used with *would*, like *I would sing* as a repeated action in the past. As for the subjunctive, could you provide an example to see where *yo cante = I sang*? I have never seen this. The same for *yo cantara = I sing*? Or *yo hubiese cantado = I have sung*? I don't think those forms are correct.

Comment: @Ustanak native speaker? mind to answer?

Comment: @Phil I'm a native speaker but I don't want to provide an answer since Yay's one is good but I need first to get my hesitations answered.

Comment: @Ustanak Will you understand if you see literary tenses?

Comment: @Ustanak *yo cantaba* is something between *I sang* and *I was singing*. None of those capture the whole meaning of *yo cantaba*, so I decided to go with both. *I would sing* is indeed a good alternative. I didn't want to put it to not create confusion with the conditional form, but it is the most appropiate translation. I'll edit the *yo cante/yo hubiera cantado* part.

Comment: @Yay Thanks for the edit, that made it clear for learners.

Comment: Me parece (es una opinión) que el futuro "cantaré" es más cercano a lo literario o al menos es muy formal. Lo que usamos en la vida diaria es "voy a cantar". Soy chileno, no sé si se dará esto en otros países.

Comment: @Rodrigo Sí, en Chile se da más el uso del *voy* más que del futuro. Pero en inglés hay una sutileza muy paricular entre el *I'm going to sing* o *I'll sing.*